# Bonding Carbon Fiber to Metal

Tags: applied-chemistry

I have an application for a very thin, strong, electrical conductor that need to act as a (almost) frictionless support "rope". Typically materials like tungsten wire or platinum-iridium alloys have been used. I was wondering about carbon fiber. However, how could I bond it to a metal (brass?) support such that significant tension would not pull it free?

The kind of thickness would be around 100 microns, for a length of maybe 30mm supporting (in the middle) up to 20 grams as it bridges a gap of 20mm.